# how do structures behave in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I was reading the following code from a tutorial when I was stuck with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
 int roll;
 string name;
 Node *next;
};

void append (Node *front, Node *newnode) {

 Node *n = front;
 if (n==NULL) return;
 while (n->next != NULL) n = n->next;
 n->next=newnode;
}




int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

 int choice;
 int roll;
 string s;

 Node *front = NULL;
 Node *n;


 while (true) {
   cout << "choice? (0:create and append, 1:find 2:exit)" << endl;
   cin >> choice;
   switch (choice) {
    case 0: cout << "roll?"; cin >> roll; 
        cout <<"name?"; cin >> s;
        n = new Node(); 
        n->roll=roll; n->name=s;
        n->next=NULL;
        if(front==NULL) front = n;
        else append (front, n);
        break;
    case 1: cout << "roll?"; cin >> roll;
        n=front;
        if (n==NULL) break;
        while ((n->next != NULL)&&(n->roll!=roll)) n = n->next;
        if (n->roll==roll) cout << n->name << endl; 
        else cout << "not found\n";
        break;
    case 2: return 0;
    default: cout << "unrecognized choice\n";
  }
 }
}
```

I am not getting how are they creating different entries using the same structure "node".
Also what does `new node()` do?
also can some one please explain how does the function append work? How does it append new entries at the end??

Comment: Thought about reading a book on C++, with a language like that, it is very much adviced

Comment: Are you familiar with pointers at all? If not I recommend reading into that as you will probably not understand any explanations without that.

Comment: I read a book - cohoon Davidson but most books dont talk about structures in great detail, especially pointers...

Comment: I am very much familiar with pointers, Argote....u can explain...i am not only getting how do they use pointers here to create different objects using a single pointer....the use of pointer front is understood but for incrementing a memory location, we usually do A+1 and not the sort of stuff done here, isn't it?

Comment: @Frustrated: any GOOD C++ book will talk about pointers, else it's not worth reading!

Comment: OK, it seems others have explained by now. As a side note, I'd advise against using single line `if` and `while` blocks (especially without brackets) as that hinders code readability and could lead to confusion.

Comment: The book might also explain that `new Node()` creates a new node.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, a struct is the same as a class - except for default 'public' access. The difference is mostly to do with developing preferences; most developers consider a class an object with methods and members and inheritence, whereas a struct just binds together a few elements.

This code creates new entries by creating new "nodes". Whist it uses the same structure for each node, it links each one with the next one on the list (through the "next" pointer - it points to the next node in memory).

As for the `new node()` section, this just allocates memory (and a few more things, but I'll assume that because you're new with C++ you don't want the boring details!

Perhaps you need a tutorial? Try [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial)!

Answer (score 2):

This is a linked list. Each node object (new creates a new instance of the struct Node which is then a object of type Node). The front node is set first if not earlier set. This is usually known as the head of a linked list. Thereafter each new "roll" value will be set to a new instance and appended to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Simple explanation:

```
void append (Node *front, Node *newnode) {

 Node *n = front;  // assign front to a tempory Node pointer called n
 if (n==NULL) return;  // if n == NULL (points to nothing) then get out of here.
 while (n->next != NULL) n = n->next;  // loop through all node's starting from n, until n->next is NULL (points to nothing)
 n->next=newnode; // assign newnode to last n->next which is the end of the node tree
}
```